# Broken text formatting in the Vote Down popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, popups

When I click on a downvote arrow without having the required reputation on that site, this is what I'm seeing:

[image: Screenshot of the Vote Down popup]

Checked it on five different sites, both graduated and beta. Same thing everywhere.

Right now I'm in Chrome under Vista, in case that matters.

Comment: It's happening for me too (AskUbuntu and Spanish Language).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whooops!

Turns out that markdown can't be treated as normal text and be expected to convert to HTML all by itself.

My bad - I was converting a bunch of strings and missed the markdown on this.

Fixed now.

Comment: [Some leftovers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242927/markdown-shorthands-like-help-dont-get-converted-to-the-appropriate-html-in-t)