# Markdown shorthands like [help] don't get converted to the appropriate HTML in the close votes queue

Tags: bug, review, markdown-rendering

From e.g. [this review](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/review/close/3658) at Hinduism.SE:

[image: Markdown rendering shenanigans]

The off-topic reason is given as:

> **off-topic:** This question does not appear to be about Hindu religion, within the scope defined in the [help].

`[help]` should probably render as a link to the help center instead, the way it does in the vote-to-close dialog:

> **off-topic:** This question does not appear to be about Hindu religion, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Perhaps this is related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242885/224428.

Comment: This stems from the same issue that Oded is fixing. I marked as duplicate.

Comment: @senshin - the issue in the potential dupe was apparently fixed yesterday, can you confirm if you still see the issue now? It might be a separate issue on a different system.

Comment: I saw this in the close vote queue literally right before I made this post 4 hours ago.